# how to re use entire testcase in another spec file in protractor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, automation, protractor

i have tried this code to re use test cases in another spec files but it is showing errors. i have used protractor with typescript

```
           login-spec.ts

            export const test = function() {
            describe("login", () => {
            it("login",async()=>{
             //lines of code
            })



        function-spec.ts

        import {test} from './login-spec.ts'

              describe("login", () => {
              it("function",async()=>{
                await test();
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for but I think it would be better in this case to write a helper file (or page object) which exports the login functionality which you can re-use across any tests. You could call this function in a beforeEach

**loginPO.js**

```
module.exports.login = function(username, password){
    //Login functionality code

    element(by.linkText('log in')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    element(by.id('loginUsername')).sendKeys(username');
    element(by.id('loginPassword')).sendKeys(password);
}
```

**testSpec.js**

```
const loginFuncs = require('./loginPO');

beforeAll(function(){
    loginFuncs.login('admin', 'adminPassword');
});
```

Comment: no, this is not what i asked. in my case i need to reuse login function with different parameters in different pages.. so  i need to use entire test case in another file

Comment: @praveen understood this is not what you were asking, I still feel this is an advisable approach however. I've updated the answer to show how it can work using parameters. If you declare the login functionality as it's own test then you will have a lot of unnecessary overhead for every test which will call it, in your case that will be almost every test.